# Template code to determine if an Exp:resso Store order was placed by a registered member?

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon

In the template that shows an order from the hash in the URL (via the `{exp:store:orders}` tag), I want to check if the order was placed by a registered member or not. If it wasn't placed by a registered member, then I want to show a message suggesting that they register to keep all their orders together.

My first thought was to see if the order has an associated `{username}`, and show the message if not. However, it [seems like `{username}` doesn't work inside `{exp:store:orders} tags](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/27235/cant-get-username-or-screen-name-to-work-inside-expstoreorders-tag), despite the docs claiming they do.

The only other thing I can think of is to pass the `{order_email}` field, which *does* work, on to some other tag that searches through members:

```
{exp:memberlist:fictional_tag search:email="{order_email}"}
    {if no_results}
    {!-- Order placed by non-member; show 'Consider Registering' message --}
    {/if}
{/exp:memberlist:fictional_tag}
```

As you may have guessed, such a tag does not appear to exist as far as I can tell.

Is there any other way to see if an order was placed by a registered member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [member_id](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/orders_tag.html#member_id) tag to see if the user is a member or not. Logged in members will have a their member_id while guest members will return 0.

{exp:store:orders order_hash="{segment_3}"}
{if member_id == 0}
Create an account to keep all orders
{/if}
{/exp:store:orders}

Comment: Great, thanks. So looks like the documentation is lacking in addition to being misleading. :-/ I hope Exp:resso and DevDemon sort this out once the transition is complete.